# About the location of prime numbers

Tags: real-analysis, prime-numbers

Let $[a,b]$ be a real interval. Let $θ=b-a$. My question is: What is the konwn values for $a,b,θ$ in which $[a,b]$ contain at least one prime number.  For example if $θ>1000$ can we deduce that still the interval $[a,b]$ contain at least one prime number for all postive $a,b$.

Comment: Well, no.  Because we can always find some interval with 1001 composite numbers in a row.  Or 10,000.  Or a million.  Or a googol.  The only thing is that to find 1001 composite in a row, the a may need to be pretty large  But that numbers from $1002! +2$ so $1002! + 1002$ are all composite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't deduce this. In fact for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$ there's a sequence of $N$ consecutive natural numbers, where none of theme is a prime number. Such a sequence is for example given by
 $$a_k:=(N+1)!+k, k=2,...,N+1.$$

Answer (score 1):

Prime numbers get rarer as you go along.  Near $N$, roughly one number in $\ln N$ is prime.

Near a million, roughly one number in fourteen is prime, so gaps have length 14, on average.  Near a google, the gaps are 230 on average; near a googleplex, the gaps are twice a googol.

In 2013, Yitang Zhang proved that, every now and again, you find a gap less than 70 million.  Other people, in particular James Maynard and Terry Tao, quickly reduced that to a gap of 246.

Many people believe there are infinitely many 'twin primes', like 29 and 31,  that are only two apart, but no-one can prove that.